# When to use Flag as duplicate?

Tags: support

When should a question be

- flagged as duplicate and
- voted to close as duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the [privilege to close questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), flagging through "should be closed..." just casts a normal close vote. There is **no difference** between the options in the flag dialog and the close dialog when you're over 3,000 rep.

Under the hood, a close flag just sends a post to the Close Votes review queue without adding a close vote (because the flagger doesn't yet have the privilege). Close flagging as a user with > 3000 rep would be pointless, because you can just directly vote to close (which automatically sends it to the review queues).

In short: *they're the same thing, and it really doesn't matter which you choose*.

Comment: Also from your link, *'Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now.'*

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Indeed, there's no need to custom flag after you get vote to close privileges (although flagging with "in need of moderator intervention" is not particularly common anyway, and might be declined as not using a standard flag). In theory, the flagging system means that the moderators never need to close questions by themselves; instead, the community can decide to do it, which is always a good thing.